# How to draw intersection of a plane and a sphere?

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying draw a circle is intersection of a plane has equation `2 x − 2 y + z − 15 = 0`  and the equation of the sphere is `( x − 1)^2 + ( y + 1)^ 2 + ( z − 2)^ 2 − 25 = 0`.
With the plane, I tried

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] := 15 - 2 x + 2 y;
Graphics3D[ {Red, 
  Polygon[Flatten[#, 1] &@{#[[1]], #[[2]], 
       f[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@ {{-10, -10}, {-10, 10}, {10, 
      10}, {10, -10}}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

and the sphere, I tried

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{1, -1, 2}, 5]}]
```

Sphere and plane, I tried

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] := 15 - 2 x + 2 y;
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cyan, Sphere[{1, -1, 2}, 5]}, {Red, 
  Polygon[Flatten[#, 1] &@{#[[1]], #[[2]], 
       f[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@ {{-10, -10}, {-10, 10}, {10, 
      10}, {10, -10}}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

I only get
[image]

How can I get the correct result?

Comment: One way is to use `InfinitePlane` for the plane and `Sphere` for the sphere.  Visualize (draw) them with `Graphics3D`.  Then use `RegionIntersection` on the plane and the sphere, not on the graphical visualization of the plane and the sphere, to get the circle.  Draw the intersection with `Region` and `Style`.  Use `Show` to combine the visualizations.

Comment: It is important to note that your syntax is incorrect in your sphere and plane attempt, hence the red highlighting of the output.

Comment: @LouisB Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @LouisB I tried like this. It seems incorrect at `reg = RegionIntersection[sph, hp];` . How can I repair?
`R = 4;
h = R - 5;
v1 = {0, 0, h};
n1 = {0, 0, 1};
sph = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, R];
hp = Hyperplane[n1, v1];
reg = RegionIntersection[sph, hp];
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], sph}, {Opacity[.5], hp}}, Boxed -> False]`

Comment: It's a little tricky because we draw the sphere and plane with `Graphics3D`, but we draw the intersection with `Region` and `Style`.  Then we use `Show` to combine two.  This should give it to you:  `Show[Region[Style[reg, Thick, Black]],
 Graphics3D[{{Blue, Opacity[.2], sph}, {Orange, Opacity[.5], hp}}]]`

Comment: @LouisB Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := 15 - 2 x + 2 y;
reg1 = Polygon[
   Flatten[#, 1] &@{#[[1]], #[[2]], 
       f[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@ {{-10, -10}, {-10, 10}, {10, 
      10}, {10, -10}}];
reg2 = Sphere[{1, -1, 2}, 5];
int = DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.5], Cyan, reg2}, {Red, reg1}, {Yellow, 
   Thickness[.02], int}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Another ways is use `ContourPlot3D`.

```
f[x_, y_] = 15 - 2 x + 2 y;
g[x_, y_] = (x \[Minus] 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2 + (z \[Minus] 2)^2 \[Minus] 
   25;
c = 6;
ContourPlot3D[{g[x, y] == 0, f[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1 - c, 
  1 + c}, {y, -1 - c, -1 + c}, {z, 2 - c, 2 + c}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y]], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, MeshStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Yellow}, 
 ContourStyle -> {{Opacity[0.5], Cyan}, Red}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]